# Google Analytics filter pages that does not have extension

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I have a number of pages in my site which respond through extensions. I want to be able to include in a report only the pages that don't have the `.php` extension, but all the other ones (like `.html, .cfm, .aspx` or no extension at all). How can I do that?

I've tried creating a filter but got stuck on the correct way to build the regex. I created the code bellow, but it is not filtering out the pages that don't have the `.php` extension.

```
(.*(?!(\.)php))$
```

what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your advanced filter, or advanced segment, should look like this.[image: this]

Comment: ok, will try that, thanks. But now something occured to me. Is it possible to do somwthing like the opposite? get all the pages that don't have the ".php" extension (even the ones with no extension, like friendly urls) and replace it with the ".php" extension?

Comment: If you're asking if you can rename the pages, then yes.  Though it would require a couple of advanced custom profile filters, or search and replace profile filters.  I wouldn't recommend it just to append a false ".php" to the end of all of your pages.

Answer (score 3):

Your code uses negative lookaheads. This regex feature is not supported by Google Analytics.

It might be confusing because some time ago this would work. At some point google removed negative lookaheads, but it was never officially supported.

Look here for a list of supported REGEX features in Google Analytics:

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034324

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies why it wouldn't work, despite some old blog posts saying negative lookahead worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about using "Include only" filter instead of "Exclude"?

Comment: yes, that is what I was thinking about, but I want to include all options **but .php** How do I do that?

Comment: Well, then simply add php exclude filter. All other files will go thru. Or where is the problem?